# Cassandra Timestamp behavior with Select query

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh, spring-data-cassandra

I have a column "postingdate" with datatype timestamp in Cassandra. I am using spring data Cassandra to save current date/time in this column when posting happens (Instant.now()). This is inserting date/time in UTC.

I have to select records which got posted on "2018-11-06". In table I have one record posted on this date and postingdate column is showing that as "2018-11-07 04:25:24+0000" in UTC.

I am running following query -

> select * from mytable where id='5' and postingdate >=
>   '2018-11-06 00:00:00' and postingdate <= '2018-11-06 23:59:59';

Running this query on Dev Center console (or CQLSH), is giving me same results irrespective of timezone. I tried that in PST as well as IST and got the same result. Is Cassandra doing PST -> UTC OR IST -> UTC conversion before executing the query? If yes then how?

Answer (score 1):

Per [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/upsertTimestamp.html):

> When timezone is excluded, it's set to the client or coordinator timezone.

You can configure default timezone for CQLSH either by setting the `TZ` environment variable, or by specifying the `timezone` parameter in the [`cqlshrc` configuration file](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.0/tools/cqlsh.html#pytz).

Comment: Thanks @Alex. My coordinator timezone is in PST. So my ask is irrespective of timezone if someone wants to get postings of 11/06, they should get 1 result because actually 1 posting happened on 11/06. What should I do for that?

Comment: You should always work with dates as stored in GMT, and do the adjustments to your local zone in queries. People who are working with data may not know where server is located, or server could be moved to other DC in another timezone, and then what will happen?